# Simplest way to reset browser curosr to default? I have a grey circle

Tags: css, angularjs

I am developing a browser based app using AngularJs.

About a week ago, I notice that the cursor had changed to a grey circle. However, I was in the throes of development and just kept coding. Now so much has changed that a diff with a previous version won't help me find the cause, and I can't see anything obvious in the code.

Is thare any sledgehammer way to rest it? I was thinging of setting a CSS style on the `<biy>` element, but that did no thelp.

I am sure that I am not setting the cursor. Perhaps it is done by some JS library which I use. Is there an easy way to override this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: `body { cursor:default }` does that work?

Comment: Did you try just `* {cursor: default}` or `* {cursor: default !important}` in your CSS? `*` for changing everywhere, for each element. You can also customise cursor view for every element you want

Comment: If the grey circle is opaque and you are using chrome with the device toggled to mobile / tablet, then you can't change the cursor - it is just showing you where your finger would be - there is no cursor on a mobile or tablet

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't. And yet I am sure that I am not setting the cursor. Perhaps it is done by so eJS library which I use? Is tehre an easy way to override this?

Comment: Lolx! @Pete, you are correct. That is what happnened. I was not even aware of the possibility. Feel free to post that as an answer and I will award it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the responsive mode of the website/ page, you will get a grey circle in the chrome dev tools. Because, you wont have a cursor for touch screens :)

Comment: Thansk for explaining about touch screens (and welcome to Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the following css rule:

```
html { cursor: auto !important; }
```

I guess you by 'default' you mean that you want to reset it to where the browser decides which cursor to display in a particular context, this would be `auto` in this case.

However this can only be a temporary solution and the rule that causes the cursor to be a grey circle should be eliminated. Further reference can be found here [Mozilla Developer Network : cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

Comment: aren't you missing a property?

Answer (score 1):

If the grey circle is opaque and you are using chrome with the device toggled to mobile / tablet, then you can't change the cursor - it is just showing you where your finger would be - there is no cursor on a mobile or tablet

Comment: D'oh!  You, my friend, are correct. I wasn't even aware of that possibility